# Javascript function parameter referencing html element

Tags: javascript, html, function

For fun purposes, I wanted to create a 100x100 html table with javascript and use `onmouseover` to change color. It'd be like a simple way of painting, however when I change the `onmouseover` to a `changeColor` function, the parameter is a `ClientX` and `ClientY` position and not the html element.

```
function createTabel(){
    var div = document.getElementById("paint");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.style.border = "1px solid black";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j <100; j++){
            var cell = document.createElement("td");

            cell.onmouseover = changeColor;

            cell.style.height = "3px";
            cell.style.width = "3px";
            cell.style.padding = "0";
            cell.style.margin = "0";

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    div.appendChild(table);
}
```

and the changeColor function:

```
function changeColor(cell){
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

How can I access the html element that caused the event without an id?

Comment: `event.target` will give you the dom element that caused the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try event instead:

```
function changeColor(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target; //get the current element(cell)
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    el.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please attach the event in a more robust way so that the event will work in all browsers.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    addEvent(cell, 'mouseover', changeColor); // See method in code below.
    // ...
}
```

```js
// Attach the event to all table cells.
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td')).forEach(function(td) {
  addEvent(td, 'mouseover', changeColor);
});

function changeColor(e) {
    e = e || window.event; // Is the event local or global?
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target; // The element who dispatched the event.
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

// Cross-browser event listener.
function addEvent(el, event, fn, useCapture) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(event, fn, useCapture);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('on' + event, function() {
      // Call the event with the scope of the target element.
      return fn.call(el, window.event);   
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>td1</td><td>td2</td></tr><tbody>
</table>
```

You can achieve the same effect, as described above, using a little bit of jQuery. jQuery's event listeners set the scope of the target element for you. This makes event handling a bit easier.

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').on('mouseover', 'td', changeColor);

  function changeColor(e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>td1</td><td>td2</td></tr><tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How does adding all this complexity help when `e.srcElement || e.target` is all he needed?

Comment: It is the proper way to attach an event and it is not that much different than what the poster did. Also, it handles adding events for IE versions less than 9.